# Build the project to a dist file, when reloading the page, the error occurs

Tags: vue.js

I am having a problem as follows: When I build the project (VueJS) to dist and upload to hosting, when I click on the link to another page, it's still ok.  But after I reload it, The home page is not affected, but the other subsites are affected

the problem is that it gives an error: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.  Hope the seniors will teach

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Because of urgent need, I am using hosting instead of vps

Comment: You need a proper hosting/server setup, you can find more here - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: I'm using Vite and Vue 3 don't know if it matches the link you sent me?  <3

Comment: Its universal for Vue2 and Vue3, all your routes should fallback to index.html file